# Handling time zones in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app where I get dates and times from the user through a form, these are stored in the model and later displayed back to the user.

I am located at UTC+2.

When I don't relate to timezones in any way, the time I get from the user is displayed back later a a +2 hr offset.

At what stage do I have to relate/set the time zone in order to get this consistent?

**Update**

I am still struggling with this even after reading this article.
When the user enters e.g `20.00` from a drop-down in the view, then this time is already local time.
Adding `Zone` to the date used to convert this adds additional two hours (which should already be included)

Comment: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change default time zone to yours in config/application.rb but first check the name of your time zone in:

```
rake time:zones:all
```